# How to read S3 folder in Redshift copy command which has dynamic date

Tags: sql, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, apache-nifi

I have the following S3 directory :

`s3://cluster-name/folder1/folder2/year=2023/month=03/day=07/*json_files`

JSON files are appended in this folder on a daily basis dynamically (eg. `month=03/day=08/ .. month=03/day=09/` and so on)

Note: the above s3 path is created using below expression language in Apache Nifi (putS3 object)
`folder1/folder2/year=${now():format('yyyy')}/month=${now():format('MM')}/day=${now():format('dd')}/${filename}`

Now I have the following copy command from S3 to Redshift

```
copy temp_table -- table name
from 's3://cluster-name/folder1/folder2/year=2023/month=03/day=07/' -- reading data from folders
iam_role 'xxxxxxx' 
region 'xxxxx'
format as json 'auto';
```

Now my issue is how do I read the JSON files in my copy command dynamically with the dates? This copy command will be a scheduled query so I need to frame this query in such a way that it will read the dates dynamically

I tried the below query :

```
COPY temp_table
FROM 's3://cluster-name/folder1/folder2/year=' || date_part(year, current_date)::varchar || '/month=' || lpad(date_part(month, current_date)::varchar,2,'0') || '/day=' || lpad(date_part(day, current_date)::varchar,2,'0') || '/'
iam_role 'xxxxxxx' 
region 'xxxxx'
format as json 'auto';
```

but I'm getting a syntax error in redshift [error while running the above query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KVfAd.png)

please assist in this or suggest any alternatives

Answer (score 1):

To perform dynamic SQL in Redshift (without external tooling) as you will need a stored procedure.  A stored procedure can compose the SQL and then EXECUTE the created text.  See: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_PLpgSQL-statements.html#r_PLpgSQL-dynamic-sql